# Make order by function inside model class in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_model = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(default=0 , decimal_places=0 , max_digits=8)
    discount_price = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, decimal_places=0, max_digits=8)
    
    def product_all_price(self):
        if self.price > 0:
            a = sum([stock.quantity for stock in self.product.all()])
            if a == 0:
                return "0"
            if a >= 1:
                if self.discount_price:
                    discount_price = str(self.discount_price)
                    price = str(self.price)
                    return 0 ,discount_price,  price
                else:
                    return str(self.price)
        else:
            return "0"
```

my views:

```
def products_list(request):
    products_list = Product.objects.filter(product_draft=False)
    products_list = products_list.order_by('-created_on')
    ...
```

How can i order this list by `product_all_price` in models. show returned "price", above and all returned "0", below

Comment: What is `self.product` supposed to do? THis is not part of the `Product` model, so likely defined in *another* model?

Comment: its a related name for stock class that i thought its not related to this subject and i didn't bring it here, if you think its necessary i can add

Comment: I find it quote odd that you define this in one method, since the price is not related to the quantity. It would probably make more sense to split this into two items: available and non-available, and then the price.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I understand what you mean, only way is that i do that two method you said ? there is nothing to do with current situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order with:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, ExpressionWrapper, Q

Product.objects.filter(
        product_draft=False
).alias(
    price_non_zero=ExpressionWrapper(
        Q(price__gt=0),
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )
).order_by('-price_non_zero', '-created_on')
```

Or in before [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2):

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, ExpressionWrapper, Q

Product.objects.filter(
        product_draft=False
).annotate(
    price_non_zero=ExpressionWrapper(
        Q(price__gt=0),
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )
).order_by('-price_non_zero', '-created_on')
```

This will thus list the `Product`s with a price greater than `0` first (sorted by `created_on` in decending order); and then the items with price `0` (again sorted by `created_on` in descending order).

Comment: thanks for answering, but after adding new product and setting price at that moment it never become zero, `product_all_price` do something with quantity and then return zero or  price, and price can be discounted or or regular price, cant we do same with output of `product_all_price` ?

Comment: @MehranBahrami: it is not clear to me exactly *what* you want to achieve. Perhaps you can edit the question and show some sample data together with the expected outcome.

Comment: I made change! zero in template show unavailable because more than one stock  quantity is zero